# Network Manager Ethernet Disappeared after installed gnome-desktop on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, apport

Can anyone assist to resolve this issue.

I installed Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 a few days ago. I noticed it was console only, so I installed *gnome-desktop* via `apt`. After rebooting I noticed my network-manager was missing from the desktop. I also noticed *snap* cannot update via the GUI. See images.

**Here is the apport log:**

```
ERROR: apport (pid 7979) Fri Oct 20 00:13:26 2023: called for pid 7361, signal 6, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 7979) Fri Oct 20 00:13:26 2023: executable: /usr/bin/gjs-console (command line "gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/ding.js -E -P /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com -M 0 -D 0:0:1366:768:1:27:0:0:0:0")
ERROR: apport (pid 7979) Fri Oct 20 00:13:27 2023: debug: session gdbus call: (true,)
ERROR: apport (pid 7979) Fri Oct 20 00:13:28 2023: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_bin_gjs-console.1000.crash
```

Screenshots
[image]

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwEwh.png]

Comment: Ubuntu Server does not come with a GUI by default. Perhaps you would prefer a full Desktop installation. If so, I suggest simply re-installing Ubuntu Desktop.